# Extract all possible combinations of unique elements in dict of lists

Tags: python, list, sampling

I have this input:

```
d = {'a': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'b': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'c': ['D', 'E'], 'd': ['E', 'F', 'G']}
```

How can I extract all the possible unique samplings per list?
One of the possible output is for example:

```
d = {'a': 'A', 'b': 'B', 'c': 'D', 'd': 'E'}
```

or

```
d = {'a': 'B', 'b': 'A', 'c': 'E', 'd': 'F'}
```

and so on..
Any idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for

```
import itertools
keys, values = zip(*d.items())
permutations_dicts = [dict(zip(keys, v)) for v in itertools.product(*values)]
```

Comment: Uhm yes, but all each element should be unique in all the dict, so for example this {'a': 'A', 'b': 'A', 'c': 'D', 'd': 'G'} is not accepted! Need to filter later (or before) I guess!

Comment: So, something like: permutations_dicts = [dict(zip(keys, v)) for v in itertools.product(*values) if len(set(v)) == 4]

Comment: Ah I didnt read the unique part my bad. This should give you a good start though. I would pass permutations_dicts through a function that:
for each key->
    get the key value ->
    for all other keys->
         check if this value is equal to the one above->
          if yes, exclude me